# EntityFramework FluentAPI mapping issue

Tags: entity-framework-4, mapping, fluent-interface

I have the following code:

```
namespace DynamicAssembly {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Data.Objects;
    using System.Data.EntityClient;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;


    [Table("eElementDef1")]
    public class ElementDef1  {

          public int pID { get; set; }
              public virtual ElementDef2  Pointer_EntityDef2 { get; set; }
              public virtual ElementDef1  Poniter_EntityDef1 { get; set; }

        public ElementDef1() {
        }
    }

    [Table("eElementDef2")]
    public class ElementDef2 {


          public int pID { get; set; }
          public String  Name { get; set; }

        public ElementDef2() {
        }
    }

    public class Context : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {

          public DbSet<ElementDef1>  ElementDef1 
            { 
               get;set;
            }
          public DbSet<ElementDef2>  ElementDef2 
            { 
               get;set;
            }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
                  modelBuilder.Entity<ElementDef1>().HasKey(c => c.pID);

modelBuilder.Entity<ElementDef1>().HasRequired(p => p.Pointer_EntityDef2)
                                                                        .WithMany()
                                                                        .IsIndependent()
                                                                        .Map(m => m.MapKey(p => p.pID, "Pointer_EntityDef2")); 


modelBuilder.Entity<ElementDef1>().HasRequired(p => p.Poniter_EntityDef1)
                                                                        .WithMany()
                                                                        .IsIndependent()
                                                                        .Map(m => m.MapKey(p => p.pID, "Poniter_EntityDef1")); 

          modelBuilder.Entity<ElementDef2>().HasKey(c => c.pID);



        }

        public Context() : 
                base("DynamicDefinitionConnection") {
        }
    }

}
```

the problem is with this mapping 
modelBuilder.Entity().HasRequired(p => p.Pointer_EntityDef2)
.WithMany()
.IsIndependent()
.Map(m => m.MapKey(p => p.pID, "Pointer_EntityDef2"));

The db does not respect de convention, the FK is not Pointer_EntityDef2pId
Is it possible that in my class to have only 1 property (Pointer_EntityDef2 of type EntityDef2) instead of 1 property for the id and one for the object (this one works ok), and the property to have the FK name? And how should the mapping look like?

Answer (score 0):

This fluent API gives you the desired schema (no need to call Map() after IsIndependent()):

```
[Table("eElementDef1")]
public class ElementDef1
{
    public int pID { get; set; }
    public virtual ElementDef2 Pointer_EntityDef2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ElementDef1 Poniter_EntityDef1 { get; set; }
}

[Table("eElementDef2")]
public class ElementDef2
{
    public int pID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class StackoverflowContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ElementDef1> ElementDef1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ElementDef2> ElementDef2s { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<ElementDef1>().HasKey(c => c.pID);
      modelBuilder.Entity<ElementDef2>().HasKey(c => c.pID);

      modelBuilder.Entity<ElementDef1>().HasRequired(p => p.Pointer_EntityDef2)
                                        .WithMany()
                                        .IsIndependent();

      modelBuilder.Entity<ElementDef1>().HasRequired(p => p.Poniter_EntityDef1)
                                        .WithMany()
                                        .IsIndependent();
    }
}
```